# How to change the order of servers in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

In the Repository Explorer of Jaspersoft Studio, I'd like to change the order of the servers I am connected to. Under "Servers", I have 3 servers, DEV, PROD and TEST, and I'd like them to be DEV, TEST and PROD. I have tried to click and drag, with no results. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Is is not currently possible (current version 6.3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible, it is ordered by name. Try to name them in alphabetical order. Create a request for enhancement on Jaspersoft Studio Site.